# What do you call someone skilled in researching quickly?

Tags: single-word-requests

Having looked through the [synonymous for researcher](http://thesaurus.com/browse/researcher) and come across the following definition of an investigator as a:

> person who checks thoroughly

is there a word, or phrase that describes

> a person who checks rapidly

without implying sloppiness or inaccuracy.

Comment: Bonus: First correct answer is automatically self-referential!

Comment: Reminds me of a quick study.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That dude's a [**whiz**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/whiz) at numbers research, a regular math [maven](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maven).

Oddly enough, [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whiz) looks to have a better def for whiz than [Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/whiz). 'Whiz' might be a little slangy, but it's been around nearly a hundred years now.

Comment: I voted for _whiz_ as I can see the association with rapid activity.

Answer (score 9):

A Librarian.

This answer is half joke, but only half. Anybody whose ever gone to a Librarian with a question can tell you a good story or two about them coming back with a good answer in an astonishingly small amount of time. Knowing where to look for just about any information at all is these folks' calling, and they tend to be amazingly good at it.

Comment: I agree that Librarians generally exhibit preternatural search abilities, but I have encountered some that appear to prefer the thorough approach, occasionally bordering on exhaustive.

Answer (score 7):

How about just an **efficient researcher**? If you want something a little more artful, you could use the phrase **human search engine**.

Answer (score 7):

Resourceful - 
Capable or clever; able to put available resources to efficient or ingenious use; using materials at hand wisely or efficiently.

Answer (score 6):

Chances are, they have *[google-fu](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Google-fu)*.

[image: http://iwastetoomuchtimeatwork.blogspot.com/2009/01/my-google-fu-is-strong.html]

Comment: For etymology, see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47694/when-did-things-like-fu-start-to-spread

Answer (score 4):

I cannot think of a single word for this. However, you could say he or she is *an efficient investigator*. [Efficient is defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/efficient)

> Functioning or producing effectively and with the least waste of effort; competent

Or he or she is *a capable investigator*. [Capable is defined as:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/capable)

> Having the ability required for a specific task or accomplishment; qualified

Comment: Efficient and Capable are certainly relevant adjectives, however, I wanted to replace the connotation of searching exhaustively, with that of searching rapidly so reinforcing investigator is out for me.

Comment: Sorry...what do you mean by "reinforcing investigator" in your comment?

Comment: You added them as adjectives to improve or elevate investigator, which to me, inflates or magnifies the thoroughly part of the given definition, whereas I was looking to replace the definition all together.

Answer (score 0):

[Eagle-eye](http://urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=eagle%20eye)

The-zero-latency-guy.

Or both, like 'Nye the science guy'.

(@JeffSahol: I saw the Q. just now.)