# Idiom for being skilled

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, slang

There's a recently-created idiom to assert that one has skills, and I don't remember what it is. It sounds like it was created by a Millennial. I want to say it has either a martial-art or science-fiction vibe, but it might be just a little silly wordplay.

It's something along the lines of:

- "My troubleshooting game is strong."
- "She has good birdwatching force."
- "He has mad baby-sitting skillz."

I think it takes the form of: "My `[skill]` `<idiom>` is good." where `[skill]` is replaced by whatever the skill or field is, and `<idiom>` is the word I can't remember.

Please suggest alternate expressions that have originated in about the past few years (post-2010) that one might use to claim proficiency with a skill.

Comment: [*-fu*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fu) (6)?

Comment: Yes! That's it. Please make it an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: related: [What does the suffix “‑fu” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3306/what-does-the-suffix-fu-mean)

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide transparent, objective criteria for useful answers. We need this when answering and voting. This applies to mind-reading games, such as “what is the word I have forgotten”, which hide usefulness criteria in the mind of the asker. See: “[Let’s Play The Guessing Game – Stack Overflow Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/)”, and “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: I've added the 'slang' tag, as the answer is flagged as such by Wiktionary. And 'snow-clone' seems more appropriate than 'idiom'. Though idiomaticity and degree of productivity don't seem to agree with those suggested in the question.

Comment: 'slang' is probably appropriate. I get why you would think of it as a snow-clone. Maybe "idiomatic phrasing" rather than straight-up idiom. I'm not entirely sure why proper classification and taxonomicalization (not a real word) of every little expression is vital to the survival of these questions and answers, but I'll go along with it. I know, I know: "Take it to the meta- site, Alan. It doesn't belong here." Right, right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom in question is the ending [*-fu*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-fu#English) (wiktionary)

> Suffix[edit]
>
> -fu
>
> (slang) Used to form nouns indicating expertise or mastery of specified skill or area of knowledge
> My Google-fu is weak!
> Aragorn uses Ranger-fu to figure out that Sam and Frodo have taken a boat.

It comes from [kung-fu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kung_fu_(term)), most commonly seen as *google-fu*

Comment: Please attribute references (it's a legal requirement). // This being a UD reference does not guarantee that the practice is generally seen as standard.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth my own experience confirms it as common, at least in several regions of the US, and the OP confirmed it's the specific term he was looking for. If you can find a better citation, feel free to edit it in or tell me and I'll do so.

Comment: The paucity of relevant internet examples for eg "driving-fu" argues against it being 'an idiom' at the moment.  It's not seen in reputable dictionaries, and OP doesn't add the tag 'slang'. I can't find a single one for "birdwatching-fu" or "baby[-]sitting-fu". / An attribution is more than a citation; you need to spell out where you take your reference from.

Comment: @Kevin One of the things Edwin Ashworth is asking you to do is fully identify your source in the answer itself, not just as a link. See: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: That seems awfully picky, but whatever.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth found it on wiktionary

Comment: Cite this chap if you like https://english.stackexchange.com/a/3308/44619, the answer was posted 8 years ago!